# php подключение файла в таблицу

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, возникла такая проблема имеются три одинаковых таблицы, содержимое которых подключается из другого файла php, но почему то содержимое подгружается только в первую таблицу,[image: введите сюда описание изображения] остальные остаются пустыми. Как это исправить?

Вот мой код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<?php include ROOT . '\views\layaut\heder_admin.php'; ?>

  <body>
        <div class="container">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span><a href="">Добавить клиента</a></button>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Клиент</th>
                        <th>Телефон</th>
                        <th>Вид услуг</th>
                        <th>Статус</th>
                        <th>Цена</th>
                        <th>Выполняет</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php include_once(ROOT . '/views/admin/client_list/client_list.php');?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                    </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h3>Клиенты в ожидании </h3>
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Клиент</th>
                        <th>Телефон</th>
                        <th>Вид услуг</th>
                        <th>Статус</th>
                        <th>Цена</th>
                        <th>Выполняет</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php include_once(ROOT . '/views/admin/client_list/client_list.php');?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h3>Мои клиенты</h3>
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Клиент</th>
                        <th>Телефон</th>
                        <th>Вид услуг</th>
                        <th>Статус</th>
                        <th>Цена</th>
                        <th>Выполняет</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php include_once(ROOT . '/views/admin/client_list/client_list.php');?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

а чего вы ожидали от [`include_once`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.include-once.php) ?

Используйте вместо этого [`include`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.include.php), либо вынесите логику вывода в отдельную функцию, подключите файл через [`include_once`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.include-once.php) вначале, а в нужном месте вызовите эту самую функцию `<?php my_function(); ?>`

И вот совет к использованию [`include`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.include.php): не пишите (), это не функция, а языковая конструкция